# Angular: Have a link if the index is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list in angular of about 40 items using ng-repeat. For the first item in the array, I need to prevent it from linking anywhere if it is clicked on.

So I used this ng-href to evaluate the index and then link to the right detail page.

```
 ng-href="{{(0 < $index) ? 'index.html#/detail/' + item.id : ''}}"
```

Works fine on load, but when I scroll away from the list, the first item actually picks up the link from the previously visited item. Is there something wrong with the express? Or is there a better 
way to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

[Here is a demo](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/dfLkb), if you click on the first item, the link will be disabled, but if you scroll down, then go back up, the first item will like to the previously visited one

Comment: Better use `$first ? ...`. This snippet looks correct. They problem may be somewhere else. Are you mutating the list?

Comment: Yeah `$first` could work, didn't think about it. Only manipulation being done is CSS depending if it it is in the viewport

Comment: It works for me: [http://jsbin.com/dufik/1/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/dufik/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Hmm let me show you my example. Adding a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer but can't tell you why.  If you change the `ng-href` to `href` it will work. It seems the ionic directive is doing something weird with whatever might be entering the viewport and is not updating itself correctly.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KolkD

```
<a class="item my-item item-thumbnail-left"
                 collection-repeat="pet in pets"
                 collection-item-height="90"
                 collection-item-width="'100%'"
                 href="{{(0 < $index) ? '#/detail/' + pet.id : ''}}" 

                 >
```

Comment: So odd, I'll have to let the devs know...

Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem.  If you do find out why or post a bug report, please post the link, I'd be interested in the details.

Comment: Opened and issuer for this on github.
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1674

Comment: Would be funny if they tell you to change it to a `href`.

Comment: Ha, well I'm on the team, so I'm sure we will work out an solution :)

Comment: How ironic that would have been to tell yourself to use an `href`.